# Set up automatic process for R to read directory and process?

Tags: r

I am so very very new to R. Like had to look up how to open a file in R new. Diving in the deep end. Anyway

I have a bunch of .csv files with results that I need to analyse. Really, I would like to set up some kind of automation so I can just say "go" (a function?)

Basically I have results in one file that are -particle.csv and another that are -ROI.csv. They have the same names so I know which ones match up (e.g. brain1 section1 -particle.csv and brain1 section1 -ROI.csv). I need to do some maths using these two datasets - Divide column 2 rows 2-x in -particle.csv (the row number might change but is there a way of saying row "2-No more content"?) by column 1, 5, 10, etc. row 2 in -ROI.csv (the column number will always stay the same but if it helps they are all called Area1, Area2, Area3,... the number of Area columns can vary but surely there's a way I can say "every column that begins with Area"? Also the area count and the row count will always match up)

Okay, I'm fine to do that manually for each set up results but I have over 300 brains to analyse! Is there anyway I can set it up as a process that I can apply this these and future results that will be in the same format?

Sorry if this is a huge ask!

Comment: Hi @DS14, you are on a good track by laying out exactly what needs to be done. I would approach this analysis from fundamental building blocks; load both data files for brain #1 into Excel and explore - maybe do all the manipulations manually one time (keep track!) for one file. Then load both data files for brain #1 into R. Think "I am building a script to automate this process", then start simple, ex: divide particle$column2  by ROI$column1, (then step 2.3.4...). When you break down into the smallest step, then it's easy to search stackoverflow and solutions.

Comment: A few library and function recommendations. To read\load\save CSV I like the `readr` package. For math the built in `R` functions are great. For manipulation of rows\columns\data I like `dplyr`. For selecting all columns starting with test "Area', I would use the `dplyr` function called `starts_with`, ex `df %>% select(starts_with('Area')`. (this is a good example about searching stack overflow, search for:  `[r] select columns that begin with` ).